# Three js parent rotation applied twice to child

Tags: three.js, transformation

I have this code in Threejs where I have a cone and a sphere being children to an Object3D named "sphereGroup"

inside my animate function I have the following

```
    sphere.position.x = -4;
    cone.position.x= 3 ;
    sphereGroup.rotation.y -= 2* angle ;
```

when this runs I see that the cone and sphere both rotate both around their axis AND the group center. why does this behavior happen ?

see here : http://ahmedfathishaban.herokuapp.com/index.html

I read that the order is always (T*R*S)parent * (T*R*S)child
in my case it will minimize to :  R(parent) * T(child) => Translate the cone from the group center then rotate the whole group around the group center.
So I understand the cone (or sphere) needs to rotate around the group center, without spinning around its own axis, What Am I missing ?

Comment: The problem is cone and sphere don't rotate around their axis. Since they have a pivot (or call parent) and you rotate their parent object, they look like rotation in their axis. It is kind of illusion.  For better understanding, try to simulate it in real world.

Comment: I think I understood, thank you. It became clearer when I replaced the cone with a geometry somewhat similar to a car. the car orbits the pivot  as expected. every point in the car tries to rotate in a circle around the pivot and that is what gives the illusion that the car is spinning around its own axis which it does not. Thank you very much , Selim :))